# Pyspark find entire array in master array and replace using another array

Tags: regex, replace, pyspark

I have a pandas implementation of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302862/pass-a-list-of-text-in-pandas-str-replace-function-at-once-instead-of-iterating). I want to implement this using `pyspark` for spark environment.

I have 2 `csv` files. first `csv` has `keyword` and corresponding `lookipid` column. I converted this into 2 lists in pure python.

```
keyword = ['IT Manager', 'Sales Manager', 'IT Analyst', 'Store Manager']
lookupid = ['##10##','##13##','##12##','##13##']
```

Second `csv` file has a `title` column with sample data below

```
current_title
I have been working here as a store manager since after I passed from college
I am sales manager and primarily work in the ASEAN region. My primary rolw is to bring new customers.
I initially joined as a IT analyst and because of my sheer drive and dedication, I was promoted to IT manager position within 3 years
```

I want to do find and replace using `regular expression` as well and return below output

```
current_title
I have been working here as a ##13## since after I passed from college
I am ##13## and primarily work in the ASEAN region. My primary rolw is to bring new customers.
I initially joined as a ##12## and because of my sheer drive and dedication, I was promoted to ##10## position within 3 years
```

How to do this using pyspark? Please suggest

Comment: You can use `UDF` in pyspark dataframe to replace all the values using `regex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do this using [`pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace) and a simple loop:

First, create a sample dataset:

```python
data = [
    ("I have been working here as a store manager.",),
    ("I am sales manager.",),
    ("I joined as an IT analyst and was promoted to IT manager.",)
]

df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, ["current_title"])
df.show(truncate=False)
#+---------------------------------------------------------+
#|current_title                                            |
#+---------------------------------------------------------+
#|I have been working here as a store manager.             |
#|I am sales manager.                                      |
#|I joined as an IT analyst and was promoted to IT manager.|
#+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now apply the each replacement:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

keyword = ['IT Manager', 'Sales Manager', 'IT Analyst', 'Store Manager']
lookupid = ['##10##','##13##','##12##','##13##']

for k, replacement in zip(keyword, lookupid):
    pattern = r'\b(?i)' + k + r'\b'
    df = df.withColumn(
        'current_title',
        f.regexp_replace(f.col('current_title'), pattern, replacement)
    )
```

Don't worry about the loops here as spark is lazy. If you look at the execution plan, you will see that it's smart enough to chain these operations so they all happen in one pass through the data:

```python
df.explain()
```

> == Physical Plan ==
>   *Project [regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(current_title#737,
>   \b(?i)IT Manager\b, ##10##), \b(?i)Sales Manager\b, ##13##), \b(?i)IT
>   Analyst\b, ##12##), \b(?i)Store Manager\b, ##13##) AS
>   current_title#752]
>   +- Scan ExistingRDD[current_title#737]

Finally, the output:

```python
df.show(truncate=False)
#+-------------------------------------------------+
#|current_title                                    |
#+-------------------------------------------------+
#|I have been working here as a ##13##.            |
#|I am ##13##.                                     |
#|I joined as an ##12## and was promoted to ##10##.|
#+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It did the job. I am curious though, can it be made any faster? For a list of 10000 current_titles and 100000 keyword, lookupid it took 86 seconds.

Comment: Its not scaling for the data size i want to execute. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669489/py4jjavaerror-in-spark