# In PySpark, using regexp_replace, how to replace a set of characters in a column values with others?

Tags: pyspark

I have a list List1=["BD","BZ","UB","DB"]

I need to change the specific characters in a string as shown below using the regex_replace

### pyspark df col values :

*BD*_AAAZ_D3002_BZ1_UB_DEV

### Expected output:

*BZ*_AAAZ_D3002_BZ1_DB_DEV

Comment: how do you know that UB has to be replaced with DB and not with any other value of the list like - may be BZ. It should rather be dictionary and not a list

Comment: if you can convert the list to dict, you should be able to use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231310/using-dictionary-in-regexp-replace-function-in-pyspark

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following dataframe

```
df.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------+
|col_1                   |
+------------------------+
|BD_AAAZ_D3002_BZ1_UB_DEV|
+------------------------+
```

You can use spark.sql's `functions` to get the desired answer

```
from pyspark.sql import functions

df = df.select(functions.regexp_replace('col_1', '(?<![a-zA-Z])(BD)(?![a-zA-Z]+)', 'BZ').alias("col_1"))
df = df.select(functions.regexp_replace('col_1', '(?<![a-zA-Z])(UB)(?![a-zA-Z]+)', 'DB').alias("col_1"))

df.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------+
|col_1                   |
+------------------------+
|BZ_AAAZ_D3002_BZ1_DB_DEV|
+------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi BrendanA   Thank you for your answer.  "BD_AAAZ_D3002_BZ1_UB_DEV" is a single string, where i want to replace the BD with BZ and UB with DB.  Could you please help me here.

Comment: Yep, just edited my answer to fit your use case